# Conditional maths operation on 2D numpy array checking on one dimension and doing different operations on diff dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have a 2D numpy array where column 0 is the pan rotation of a device and column 1 is the tilt rotation. Each row is a different fixture. I want to run the following logic on each row:

```
if(pantilt[0] > 90):
    pantilt[0] -=180
    pantilt[1] *= -1
elif pantilt[0] < -90:
    pantilt[0] += 180
    pantilt[1] *= -1
```

I understand basic conditional operations on 1D like myarray[condition] = something. But I can't extrapolate that into more dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would calculate a mask, or boolean index, and use if for each column:

Construct a sample array:

```
pantilt=np.column_stack([np.linspace(-180,180,11),np.linspace(0,90,11)])

I = pantilt[:,0]>90
# J = pantilt[:,0]<-90 
pantilt[I,0] -= 180
pantilt[I,1] *= -1

I = pantilt[:,0]<-90  # could use J instead
pantilt[I,0] += 180
pantilt[I,1] *= -1
```

Before:

```
array([[-180.,    0.],
       [-144.,    9.],
       [-108.,   18.],
       [ -72.,   27.],
       [ -36.,   36.],
       [   0.,   45.],
       [  36.,   54.],
       [  72.,   63.],
       [ 108.,   72.],
       [ 144.,   81.],
       [ 180.,   90.]])
```

After:

```
array([[  0.,  -0.],
       [ 36.,  -9.],
       [ 72., -18.],
       [-72.,  27.],
       [-36.,  36.],
       [  0.,  45.],
       [ 36.,  54.],
       [ 72.,  63.],
       [-72., -72.],
       [-36., -81.],
       [  0., -90.]])
```

This would work just as well if the columns were separate 1d arrays.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
pantilt[:,0][pantilt[:,0]>90] -= 180
pantilt[:,1][pantilt[:,0]>90] *= -1
pantilt[:,0][pantilt[:,0]<-90] += 180
pantilt[:,1][pantilt[:,0]<-90] *= -1
```

Comment: Wow, that looks a lot simpler than I thought! It didn't occur to me to do the check twice. Though I think the indices should be swapped and a bit more complex? in the simple code I wrote (i.e. the kernel) my pantilt[0] is pan and pantilt[1] is tilt. When vectorizing into the table pantilt_array[0] will return the first pantilt entry, not the first column? likewise when doing the check, shouldn't it be pantilt_array[:, 0]>90?

Comment: Yes you're right, well spotted, I've edited my answer (I'm actually not used to using numpy arrays directly; I am usually using pandas so that the columns have names)

Comment: actually, I don't think that's going to work either! because once you overwrite the first column, the second conditional fails! So you need to do that one last. Also I don't understand the [,][] syntax. Isn't using a comma inside the [] the same as [][]? What does it mean when you use a comma inside an [] as well as an additional []?

Comment: I think it's OK: `[pantilt[:,0]>90]` is an indexer i.e., an array of booleans, which selects out the rows for which the condition is true. So only those rows are updated. Whereas `[:,0]` is a column slicer, so it return the whole first column.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [`this another related answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30567895/3293881), one can use [`masking`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) in three steps, instead of four steps as proposed in the other two solutions, like so -

```
import numpy as np

# Get mask correspindig to IF conditional statements in original code
mask_lt = pantilt[:,0]<-90
mask_gt = pantilt[:,0]>90

# Edit the first column as per the statements in original code
pantilt[:,0][mask_gt] -= 180
pantilt[:,0][mask_lt] += 180

# Edit the second column as per the statements in original code
pantilt[ mask_lt | mask_gt,1] *= -1
```

**Runtime tests**

Quick runtime tests to compare the three approaches listed so far -

```
In [530]: num_samples = 10000
     ...: org = np.random.randint(-180,180,(num_samples,2))
     ...: 

In [531]: pantilt = org.copy()

In [532]: %timeit hpaulj_mask4(pantilt)
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.7 µs per loop

In [533]: pantilt = org.copy()

In [534]: %timeit maxymoo_mask4(pantilt)
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.7 µs per loop

In [535]: pantilt = org.copy()

In [536]: %timeit mask3(pantilt) # three-step masking approach from this solution
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.1 µs per loop
```